# Proving a limit is less than or equal to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If $\lim  _{n\to\infty}x_n = x$ and if $x_n < 1$ for all n. Must it be true that $x\le1$. If yes, prove it. If no, give a counter example.

So the limit is defined as $\lvert x_n - x\rvert < \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$

Thus, $x- \epsilon<x_n<x+ \epsilon$. It is understood that $\epsilon$ is a small real number. Is it wrong to then set $\epsilon = 1$ and then say that $$ x-1 < x_n < x+1$$ which would then show that $x_n$ could possibly be greater than 1?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can I assume that x> 0 ?

Comment: Hint:  Say $x>1$.  choose $0<\epsilon<x-1$.  Is it possible for any $x_n$ to satisfy $|x-x_n|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Don't I want $\lvert x_n - x\rvert < \epsilon$? Then continuing on $$ x-\epsilon < x_n < x+ \epsilon$$ and then since we assume that $x>1 $, the upper bound for $x_n$ would be $x+(x-1) = 2x -1 $, which would then be greater than 1?

Comment: $|x-x_n|=|x_n-x|$.  But your inequalities seem useful.  If $\epsilon<x-1$ then $x-\epsilon>1$ but then...

Comment: ah so then i could say that $$1<x-\epsilon<x_n < x + \epsilon = (x -\epsilon) +\epsilon = x $$ or would I also have to subtract $\epsilon$ from the lower bound, then making this statement false?

Comment: Well, once you have $x_n>1$ you've got your contradiction. That's all you need!  To be clear:  you started from the assumption that $x>1$ and you got a contradiction; this implies that the assumption must be false.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x>1$; this necessarily implies that, for $n$ big enough, $x_n>1$.

So if $x_n\leq 1$ for all $n$, then $x\leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. If you suppose that $x>1$, then all of the $x_n$ are at least as far from $x$ as $1$ is (because $x_n<1< x$)--but then it is not possible to have $x_n\to x$ since the $x_n$ are bounded away from $x$.